# change a function to service from a component in angular

Tags: angular

Angular2: I wrote a remove function in `component.ts` where I remove an item by `id`.

How to pass that function in the service class?

Here's a funciton code:

```js
removeProduct(id: any,name:any) {
    let message='remove'
    let call = this.dialog.open(CartModelComponent, { data:{ message,name }});
    call.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result === "confirm") {
        for (let i = 0; i <= this.Cart.length; i++) {
          if (this.Cart[i]?.id == id) {
            this.Cart.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }
        localStorage.setItem('local-store', JSON.stringify(this.Cart));
        this.findTotal()
        this.noContent()
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: What is blocking you? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

1- create a service by using Angular CLI

2- move your removeProduct function to this service and add an extra parameter which is the cart array

3- after doing your remove logic return this cart array

3- inject your service into the component

4- use the remove function from the service and pass the id, name, cart array

5- store or do what u want with that array u returned

Remember to move dialog service and modal component to your new service.

Hope that you need.

Answer (score 0):

The value should be change directly in the service. Then you simply **subscribe to this value** in your `component.ts` using an **observable**.

*Like always with observable, do not forget to unsubscribe to avoid **memory leak***

Here an example

```js
// foo.service.ts
onCartChanged$: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null)

// ...

removeProduct(id: number, string) {
  const message='remove'
  const call = this.dialog.open(CartModelComponent, { data:{ message,name }});
  call.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    if (result === "confirm") {
      for (let i = 0; i <= this.Cart.length; i++) {
        if (this.Cart[i]?.id == id) {
          this.Cart.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
      localStorage.setItem('local-store', JSON.stringify(this.Cart));
      this.findTotal()
      this.noContent()
      this.onCartChanged$.next(this.Cart)
    }
  })
}
```

```js
// foo.component.ts
private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any> = new Subject()

constructor(private _fooService: FooService) {}

removeProduct(id: any,name:any) {
  this._fooService.removeProduct(id, name) // Or directly in your html but it then have to be public 
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this._fooService.onCartChanged$
    .pipe(
      filter((event) => (event ? true : false)),
      takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll), // Do not forget to unsubscribe
    )
    .subscribe((newCart) => {
      this.Cart = newCart
    })
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this._unsubscribeAll.next()
  this._unsubscribeAll.complete()
}
```